# How to automatically set enviropment variables into Qt Creator from .bashrc?

Tags: bash, qt-creator

How to automatically set environment variables into Qt Creator's build environment from .bashrc?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are starting qt creator from the command line, you can just add them like any other global variables, i.e. something as simple as `QT_VARIABLE=whatever`

Comment: don't forget to `export` them.